# How to update custom listview text view posistion in android

Tags: android

I have implemented custom list view. I have year(Textview) in the 4th row. If the user clicks year, I have to show date picker and update the date picker value in year(Textview). Can anybody tell me how to do this? Is there any iphone-style datepicker available on android?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

onlist item click u can write this line

```
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
```

in this method you can write this code

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth,
                    mDay);
```

Date time picker code

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;

            updateFromDateDisplay(false);

        }
    };

    private void updateFromDateDisplay(boolean flag) {
        String mTempDay = "", mTempMonth = "";
        if (mDay < 10) {
            mTempDay = returnProperDateMonth(mDay);
        } else {
            mTempDay = Integer.toString(mDay);
        }

        if (mMonth < 10) {
            mTempMonth = returnProperDateMonth(mMonth + 1);
        } else {
            mTempMonth = Integer.toString(mMonth + 1);
        }
        if(flag){
            startsOn.setText(new StringBuilder().append(mTempDay).append("/")
                    .append(mTempMonth).append("/").append(mYear).append(""));
        }else{

            if (mWhichDatePicker == 3) {
                startsOn.setText(new StringBuilder().append(mTempDay).append("/")
                        .append(mTempMonth).append("/").append(mYear).append(""));
                startsOn.setSelection((new StringBuilder().append(mTempDay)
                        .append("/").append(mTempMonth).append("/").append(mYear)
                        .append("")).length());
            } else if (mWhichDatePicker == 4) {
                endsOn.setText(new StringBuilder().append(mTempDay).append("/")
                        .append(mTempMonth).append("/").append(mYear).append(""));
                endsOn.setSelection((new StringBuilder().append(mTempDay)
                        .append("/").append(mTempMonth).append("/").append(mYear)
                        .append("")).length());

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                endDate = cal.getTime();
            }
        }

    }
```

and date in ur custom textview of list view .
hope its useful to you.
Thanks